# MYSQL, Create a new Query for a Column with Decimal (M,D) in the workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

At the moment I am working on VAT for each country where the Sale arrival country.

this VAT is working well and correct, however, I having an issue with 0.0000000 as I tried put coalesce with 0.00 but it keeps displayed with '3632.608266' rather than '3632.60' which I am looking for

Here are MySQL queries I wrote

```
SUM(COALESCE((TOTAL_ACTIVITY_VALUE_AMT_VAT_INCL)-(TOTAL_ACTIVITY_VALUE_AMT_VAT_INCL)/(VAT_Standard_Rate + 1),0.00)) AS 'decmical',
```

Here is a full version

```
SELECT 
    SALE_ARRIVAL_COUNTRY,
    tbl_countries.Country,
    VAT_Standard_Rate,
    SUM(COALESCE((TOTAL_ACTIVITY_VALUE_AMT_VAT_INCL)-(TOTAL_ACTIVITY_VALUE_AMT_VAT_INCL)/(VAT_Standard_Rate + 1),0.00)) AS 'decmical',
    SUM(COALESCE(TOTAL_ACTIVITY_VALUE_AMT_VAT_INCL)+(TOTAL_ACTIVITY_VALUE_AMT_VAT_INCL)/(VAT_Standard_Rate + 1)-(TOTAL_ACTIVITY_VALUE_AMT_VAT_INCL)) AS 'NET',
    SUM(COALESCE(TOTAL_ACTIVITY_VALUE_AMT_VAT_INCL)-(TOTAL_ACTIVITY_VALUE_AMT_VAT_INCL)/(VAT_Standard_Rate + 1)) AS 'VAT',
    SUM(TOTAL_ACTIVITY_VALUE_AMT_VAT_INCL) AS 'Total',
    TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_CODE as 'Currency'
FROM
    tbl_vat
INNER JOIN tbl_countries
INNER JOIN tbl_vat_rate
ON amazon.tbl_vat.SALE_ARRIVAL_COUNTRY=tbl_countries.alpha_2 AND tbl_countries.Country=tbl_vat_rate.Country_of_Purchase
GROUP BY tbl_countries.Country
```

Here is a screenshot of result with yellow highlight
[image]

Comment: S.O - why not to use double or float for currency  ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use format function from SQL for that like this:

```
FORMAT(SUM(COALESCE((TOTAL_ACTIVITY_VALUE_AMT_VAT_INCL)-(TOTAL_ACTIVITY_VALUE_AMT_VAT_INCL)/(VAT_Standard_Rate + 1),0.00)), 2) AS 'decmical',
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Round() function

```
ROUND(N,[D])
ROUND() rounds a number specified as an argument up 
to a number specified as another argument.
```

like this:

```
mysql> SELECT ROUND(-4.535,2);
+-----------------+
| ROUND(-4.535,2) |
+-----------------+
|           -4.54 | 
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

OR

You can use Truncate function

```
TRUNCATE(X,D)
Returns the number X, truncated to D decimal places
```

like this:

```
mysql> SELECT TRUNCATE(1.223,1);
    -> 1.2
mysql> SELECT TRUNCATE(1.999,1);
    -> 1.9
```

Comment: I like this function, i will notes this for this query function, thanks